# syntax error pic 18: RCNT EQU 0x20 and MYREG EQU 0x21

Tags: inline-assembly, pic

I'm using the pic 18F4550 with the C compiler from microchip v8.63. i'm using the following code from the
book "Pic microcontrollers and embedded systems using assembly and c for pic18".

On the following line code, I receive a syntax error: RCNT EQU 0x20 and MYREG EQU 0x21.

```
_asm
    RCNT EQU 0x20
    MYREG EQU 0x21

    BCF TRISB,1
    MOVLW 0x41
    MOVWF MYREG
    BCF STATUS,C
    MOVLW 0x8
    MOVWF RCNT
    BSF PORTB,1
AGAIN
    RLCF MYREG,F
    BNC OVER
    BSF PORTB,1
    BRA NEXT
    OVER BCF PORTB,1
    NEXT DECF RCNT,F
    BNZ AGAIN
    BSF PORTB,1
_endasm
```

Comment: Your C compiler/assembler probably needs a different syntax for those equates (EQU) - check the manual.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't find it..

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Microchip documentation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/c18_user_guide_51288j.pdf) assembler directives (such as `EQU`) are not supported for inline asm, so `#define` may be the only way to define equates.

Change:

```
RCNT EQU 0x20
MYREG EQU 0x21
```

to:

```
#define RCNT 0x20
#define MYREG 0x21
```